# login CodeIgniter 3 redirect the data to an other controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, controller

i have a login system in my CI application, so i follow this tutorial : [click here!](http://www.iluv2code.com/login-with-codeigniter-php.html) 
  But when i send my data using button **login** it redirect me to '**home/verifylogin**' instead '**verifylogin**'.

Comment: set your base_url in config.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the value you have put in the 'action' attribute in form tag in view page. If you want to call 'verifylogin' controller then marked at there.